# Правильно ли я разделяю подключение js файлов через webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Мне необходимо к 2 или более страницам подключить разные js файлы через webpack, я нашел решение, но хотелось бы узнать насколько оно правильное и есть ли еще какие-нибудь решения этого?

В точках входа я определяю отдельно каждый js файл

```
module.exports = {
 mode: mode,
 entry: {
   main: './src/index.js',
   user: './src/user.js',
   userTestPage: `${PAGES_DIR}testPage/user.js`
 },
```

Затем в плагине Html webpack plugin через свойство chunks задаю к какой из страниц какой js файл будет подгружаться.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.pug',
  filename: 'index.html',
  chunks: ['main, user']
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: `${PAGES_DIR}testPage/testPage.pug`,
  filename: 'testPage.html',
  chunks: ['main, userTestPage']
}),
```

Насколько это верное решение? Просто если страниц будет 10 или больше, то на мой взгляд слишком много однотипного кода будет

Comment: Ну вроде решение не такое уж и плохое. А по поводу 10 страниц и более - вебпак для такого и не предназначен, в первую очередь это инструмент для построения spa приложений. Если количество страниц будет от 10 и больше, то возможно, следует обратить внимание на gulp, внутри которого запускать webpack-stream для js файлов

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ